# Create clone of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript,

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = arr.slice();
```

`arr2` will not change if `arr` values are changed. That is, `arr[0] = 0;`, still `arr2[0] == 1; // true`.

Consider this:

```
var obj = {name: 'John', company: 'XYZ'};
var obj2 = obj; // Creates a duplicate of obj
```

But `obj.name = 'Dave'`, makes `obj2.name = 'Dave'` as well.

How can we do a `slice()` operation for objects?

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions. The answer depends on whether you want a deep or a shallow copy. Use the site search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone objects (excluding functions and prototypes) you should use structured clone.

For `node.js` I have found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/structured-clone),  but I can't tell you if it is good.

For browsers you can use this asynchronous clone function (it  depends on correct implementation of postMessage):

```
function clone(obj, callback) {
    var from = window.location.origin;
    var wrapper = {'__clone__': true};
    wrapper.__data__ = obj;
    var listener = function(e) {
        if(e.origin === from && e.data.__clone__) {
            callback(e.data.__data__);
            window.removeEventListener('message', listener);
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('message', listener);
    window.postMessage(wrapper, from);
}
```

Structured clone supports:

- primitives
- new String, new Boolean, new Number
- new Date
- new RegExp
- new Blob
- new File
- new FileList
- new ArrayBuffer
- TypedArrays
- ImageData
- Arrays
- plain objects
- Map
- Set